# Subscribe to $().ready function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

On each page I create my custom js object.

I want to subscribe to the $().ready event so that when it fires, my objects init function also fires.

Is this possible?

**Updated**

My object looks like:

```
var blah = function() {
    var init = function() {
     //init function stuff
    };
    return {
     InitPage: function() { init(); }
    };
 }();
```

Then on my page I will do:

```
blah.init();
```

Comment: You mean `blah.InitPage()`. `init` is "private".

Answer (score 9):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    YourObject.init();
});
```

Comment: As a shorthand you could do $(function(){...});

Comment: @Mark — A number of people (myself included) dislike that "shorthand" syntax, as it's less clear what it does just by looking at it.

Comment: Why you call a function within a function? Just use `$(document).ready(blah.InitPage)`

Comment: @Bondye if you use `this` inside InitPage you're kind of screwed

Comment: all i'm saying is that you have to be careful with how you use `this` inside the `InitPage` function

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am misunderstanding your question but I think what you want to do is put your initialization code inside this block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

When you pass a function to the jQuery `ready()` function it aggregates the new function with all previous functions.  In other words this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("a");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("b");
});
```

You don't have to worry about overwriting your previous `ready()` call.

Comment: I am creating an object, so from within my object I want to make sure the constructor (or my init method) is called when the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the jQuery [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn) event.

> When you bind a "live" event it will bind to all current and future elements on the page (using event delegation). For example if you bound a live click to all "li" elements on the page then added another li at a later time - that click event would continue to work for the new element (this is not the case with bind which must be re-bound on all new elements).

Example:

```
$("p").live("click", function(){
    $(this).after("<p>Another paragraph!</p>");
});
```